# PHP user authentication tutorial without sessions

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I need to build my own system for part of a computer security project without using php sessions (just cookies) and im just lost. All the tutorials ive found use sessions (for good reason) so I was wondering if anyone knew of a roll your own php user authentication tutorial.

Comment: the obvious question is why not sessions?

Comment: Professor wrote on the assignment not to use them. The assignment is really about implementing my own security features and from waht ive read session takes care of a lot of that.

Comment: You would do it in the same way, essentially. You would just save the state in the cookie instead of the session. Try googling how to generally use cookies in PHP. Come back if you can't make them work. Also, who in the world told you that session takes care of security features that cookies don't? Unless your little sister is sneaking onto the computer to read your browser's cookie files, they're not much different from a security standpoint. Sessions require that cookies are enabled to function.

Comment: Can't think of any tutorials so I won't post an answer.  You could roll your own sessions quite easily by storing a session ID in a user's cookie and having some file or database storage that you can reference by their session id (can't comment on the security of that approach, however). E.g. `$session = DB::getSession($_COOKIE['sid']);`

Comment: Did the professor just require you not to use the PHP built-in sessions or did he mean any sessions at all?

Comment: Another possibility would be to use some kind of cryptography to 'sign' the user's cookie in such a way that you can verify its authenticity, but cannot be easily duplicated by third parties (though this still leaves you vulnerable to cookie sniffing).  An asymmetric algorithm could be appropriate, such as RSA.

Comment: @Dagon You are the fool here: most sessions STILL use cookies to send and store a session id.  The professor is purposefully asking him to try to reinvent session.  I am quite sure the professor does not want the creation to be used out in the 'real world', but getting in and solving real problems on your own is extremely valuable. The fact it has already been done does not lessen the value.

Comment: perhaps, but I have a big issue with how practical subjects are taught with little or no reference to how they will be used in the *real world*.

Comment: @LeviMorrison Call me crazy but I don't see the value in teaching a student how to think abstractly about a practical, real-world programming problem. That's what your math classes are for. Teach problem solving there. Your COMPSCI classes should teach you how best to correctly solve the problem in the real world. Also, is PHP really the best language to use for teaching problem solving? Ehhh ... probably not.

Comment: @Dagon Come join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: @rdlowrey Come join me in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could basically implement something session like yourself.

This would include the following tasks:

- generate a random session id for new users (or on login - based on the exact use...)
- save it into a cookie
- do save additional session inforamtion somewhere on the server together with the session id (e.g. in a database table)
- on subsequent page accesses check the session id in the cookie versus the data on the webserver to identify users and grant access

However it should be mentioned that a cookie only based solution is never that good. If a client for example doesn't have cookies enabled it won't work at all. A possible solution for this is to send the session id as GET parameter with every internal link if cookies are not enabled.

Comment: I was about to write essentially the same thing, so I'll just +1 and add a [link about sessions and cookies](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/0/0).

Comment: +1 I have just written the same answer, but dropped it in favour of this.

Comment: Thanks, between this answer and reading up how use cookies in PHP i think im ready.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions would make it much easier. That being said, where are you getting stuck mate?

To get started using Cookies in PHP, check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

You could either

- implement your own Session handling as s1lence suggests (which might be exactly what the professor wants you to do) or
- implement your own Session handling through appending the session id to the QueryString (making it work for non-cookie browsers) or
- you could store the user/password pair in cookies (which would force you to reauthenticate the user for every request)

I wouldn't recommend the latter, but if it's all about avoiding the Session Mechanism it's an option I guess. And a last remark, if this doesn't have something to do with understanding why Session is important you should really question your teachers task.. ;)

Comment: he does want us to implement our own session handling

Answer (score -1):

You should not use cookie for such system in cause cookie are stored on the client side. And any one can change it. Sessions are stored on the server side and only you can change it (also other system users can change it if they have directory access or db access if you store sessions in db). If you strongly need to use cookie you can encrypt login/password can write to cookie, but the using of sessions is more safely.

Comment: This is dubious advice, as the session ID must still be stored in a cookie file on the client end. If a malicious person has access to the client's system, a session is no safer than a cookie.

Comment: @rdlowrey The point is that a user could deserialize the cookie and manipulate the script variables stored in it, for instance set $user_is_admin = true, and the script would reread the manipulated data during the next request and think the user has more rights than he actually does. Storing only the session ID is way safer as the client then first has to get hold of an ID which is assigned to an admin session.

Comment: @the-banana-king security isn't concerned with the legitimate user, it's concerned with the malicious user, not to mention that even `$_SESSION` data should be validated client side. The scenario you present is no more difficult to manage for a malicious person than accessing the session ID cookie. Additionally, it assumes poor internal application design and data validation: a fault that is unaffected by the use of sessions versus cookies. So yeah, if you aren't going to properly secure your application, maybe sessions are 1% safer than cookies.

Comment: @rdlowrey In fact I was talking about a malicious client who wants to extend their privileges or take advantage of being able to change some other internal state of the application. If you only have a session ID, you as a client cannot change any data that is attached to it on the server side unless the script allows you to do so.

Comment: I think we were talking about different aspects. I agree that authenticating by stealing a session ID is just as easy as stealing the full credentials out of a client's cookie, yet hijacking the session gives you access until it becomes invalid, while acquiring username and password enables you to reauthenticate as often as you want. Therefore storing the session ID is still more secure.

Comment: @the-banana-king I can agree with your logic, sir.