# How to update data of logged in user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a table called "user" that contains the following fields; username, email, password, points, latest.

Users log in via a login.php by entering their username and password into the form.

They will then be able to fill in whatever words they want in the "latest" field and click the "publish" button.

This button will run the latest.php which is shown below.

The problem is that when a user saves his/her work, it updates all user's "latest" column in the table instead of just him/her own.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-AuthToken');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include("global.php");
try{
    $conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);
    $latest = $_GET["latest"];

    $query = "update users set latest = '$latest'";
    //echo $query;
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result){
        $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";
    }
    else {
        $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";
    }
    echo $json_out;
    $conn->close();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $json_out = "[".json_encode(array("result"=>0))."]";
    echo $json_out;
}
?>
```

Comment: you forgot to add a primary key like `user_id` to your table, and then later on you can use to update which specific user you need to update

Comment: You don't have any `where` clause in your query. Maybe `update users set latest = '$latest' WHERE email={{userEmail}}`

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: In the user table, the `username` is the primary key. Sorry I did not mention that. Also, where would I have to add the `username` in the php for it to select the current user?

Comment: Do you store the `username` in session ?

Comment: No, I didn't. Is it supposed to be done in the `login.php` or `latest.php`?

Comment: You will need to store the user in `login` then remove it on `logout`. Like this, you could use your `user` in all your pages.

Comment: Maybe this could help you : https://johnmorrisonline.com/build-php-login-form-using-sessions/

Comment: Is it a must to use a session? Or are there any other ways of going about this?

Comment: It's the best way to preserve data between multiple access: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php.

Maybe you could do it by yourself without use of sessions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254822/php-user-authentication-tutorial-without-sessions.